# How to upload and move .txt file in php

Tags: php, mysqli

code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $filename = $_FILES['field']['name'];
        $path = "attandance_file/".basename($_FILES['field']['name']);
        $move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['field']['tmp_name'],$path);
        $data = file_get_contents($path, NULL, NULL, 0, 60000);
        $query = "insert into attandance(No,TMNo,EnNo,Name,INOUT,Mode,DateTime)value('".$data."')";
        echo $query;
        unlink($path);
    }
?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="field" name="field" />
        <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

example.txt:

```
No  TMNo    EnNo    Name    INOUT   Mode    DateTime
1    1       1                0      0      2017/01/03 16:41:22
2    1       1                0      0      2017/01/03 16:41:22
3    1       1                0      0      2017/01/03 16:42:39
4    1       1                0      0      2017/01/03 16:42:39
5    1       2                0      0      2017/01/03 16:59:42
```

When I click on the submit button and echo `$query`, the response I get back looks like this:

```
insert into attandance(No,TMNo,EnNo,Name,INOUT,Mode,DateTime)value('No  TMNo    EnNo    Name    INOUT   Mode    DateTime 1  1   1   0   0   2017/01/03 16:41:22 2   1   1   0   0   2017/01/03 16:41:22 3   1 1 0   0   2017/01/03 16:42:39 4   1   1   0   0   2017/01/03 16:42:39 5   1   2   0   0   2017/01/03 16:59:42')
```

How can I upload the example.txt file into the database using PHP?

Comment: Why bother calling `move_uploaded_file` if you're just going to read the contents and delete the file anyway? Just `file_get_contents($_FILES['field']['tmp_name'], ...)`

Comment: but look when i echo $query it look like single value@Phil

Comment: You could parse the file and make a query for each line of the .txt file...

`$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $data);` and then `foreach($lines as $line) { ... }` and skip the first line since it cointains column names.

Comment: If I make a query for each line. So, how is it look like ?

Comment: may any body help me out please